# Printing number of line before with putchar()

Tags: c

Please take a look at my code and tell me why my output looks like it does.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   char ch, source_file[20];
   FILE *source;
   int i=1;
   if( argc == 2 ) {
      printf("The file being displayed is %s\n", argv[1]);

   source = fopen(argv[1], "r");

   if( source == NULL )
   {
      printf("Press any key to exit...\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   while( ( ch = fgetc(source) ) != EOF )
   {
       if(ch=='\n')
       {
          putchar(ch);
          printf("%d.", i);
          i++;
       }
       if(i==1)
       {
           printf("%d.", i);
           i++;
           putchar(ch);

       }
       else
          putchar(ch);
   }

   fclose(source);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
}
```

Here's the output

```
C:>p_gui_o3_ex3.exe asd.txt

The file being displayed is asd.txt
1.Teste
2.
Teste
3.
Teste
4.

5.
asd
6.
asd
7.
asd
8.
asd
9.
asd
10.
asd
11.
asd
12.
asd
13.
asd
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you put what you want your output to look like in addition to what you are actually getting.

Comment: `if(i==1)` --> `else if(i==1)`

Comment: _I was not able to find a simple solution and don't have much time so if you would please take a look at my code and tell me why_.  Are you kidding?

Comment: Aside: newbie error `char ch` should be `int ch` because that is the return type of `fgetc()` and also the argument type for `putchar()`. May not be important in a text file, but generally file data `0xFF` will not be distinguished from `EOF`. Note too that `'\n'` is type `int`.

Comment: Instead of explaining us that you don't have much time, that you are a beginner and that your parogam is a basic C program (we've guessed that already), you'd better explain us what output exactly you want. and what the content of your `asd.txt` file is.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It worked!Would you mind explain me why I should use else if instead of if?

Comment: Why do you have `putchar()` in every `if` block. Take it out of the `if`'s, and just use one `putchar()` after the `if` block has completed.

Comment: For everyone asking this is what I wanted the output too look like

Comment: In the question, please.

Comment: `if(ch=='\n') {  }` and  `if(i==1){ } else`  are executed in duplicate.

Comment: @WeatherVane What do you mean by `0xFF`? Should I watch out for that in .dat files, and if so should I try another method of printing to the command line when I come across it?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you for the help and explanation!

Comment: `0xFF` is hexadecimal notation for decimal `255`, if your compiler's `char` is unsigned. Quite often the `char` is signed, so `0xFF` will be `-1`. But `EOF` is usually defined to be `-1` too. However, if the data type is defined to be `int` then `0xFF` data will be read as `255` and not as `-1`, and there will be no confusion between those two values. In text files you will rarely find that `0xFF` value, but in binary files you probably will.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ah!Understood,will take that in mind when making the project for the end of the semester which requires the usage of .dat files thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the issue has been fixed.
The output now looks like what I wanted and I'm working on the little tips provided by you guys.

Here's the output

```
The file being displayed is asd.txt
1.Teste
2.Teste
3.Teste
4.
5.asd
6.asd
7.asd
8.asd
9.asd
10.asd
11.asd
12.asd
13.asd
```

And here's the fixed code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   char source_file[20];
   int ch;
   FILE *source;
   int i=1;
   if( argc == 2 ) {
      printf("The file being displayed is %s\n", argv[1]);

   source = fopen(argv[1], "r");

   if( source == NULL )
   {
      printf("Press any key to exit...\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   while( ( ch = fgetc(source) ) != EOF )
   {
       if(ch=='\n')
       {
          putchar(ch);
          printf("%d.", i);
          i++;
       }
       else if(i==1)
       {
           printf("%d.", i);
           i++;
           putchar(ch);
       }
       else
          putchar(ch);
   }

   fclose(source);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
}
```

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Your source file does not end with a `'\n'`, else it would have printed `13.asd\n14.`  If the source file began with a `'\n'`, the output is `"\n1.etc."`

Answer (score 0):

> Printing number of line *before*

To print the line number *before* the line, detect if the previous character was a `'\n'`.

```
unsigned long long line = 0;
int previous = '\n';
int ch;

while ((ch = fgetc(source)) != EOF) {
  if (previous == '\n') {
    line++;
    printf("%llu.", line);
  }
  putchar(ch);
  previous = ch;
}

// With files that do not end with a \n, perhaps print a \n anyways
if (previous != '\n') {
  putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry about the broken English I wrote this in a bit of hurry since I need to do this quickly.Anyway your code seems much more tidy than mine but shouldn't I replace the `getchar()` with `fgetc()` since I'm working with .txt files?

Comment: @Kirian Yes `fgetc(source)` is a better choice because code is not using `stdin`.